# Change background of ImageButton in popup window

Tags: android, popup

I'm building an app and want to change the teamcolors in a popup window. I used ImageButtons to show the users the teamcolors. One button in the main activity and four buttons in the popup window. When I click one in the popup window, I can switch the backgrounds but when I close the popup window and open it again, the buttons in the popup window has been reseted.

How can I close my popup window without the reset?

```
public void colorchange(final View view){

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popwindow, null);
    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup);
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, relativeLayout.getWidth(), relativeLayout.getHeight(), true);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(relativeLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, (int)relativeLayout.getX(),(int)relativeLayout.getY());
    ImageButton narancs = (ImageButton) container.findViewById(R.id.imgbutton1);

    container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            return false;
        }
    });

    narancs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable asds = v.getBackground();
            Log.d("hatter", String.valueOf(asds));
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.orangebutton);
            Log.d("hatter", String.valueOf(view.getBackground()));
            //popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

This code runs on mainactivity button click event.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your answer correctly, you want to "save" the button background color on click. If that is so, you could use Shared Preferences ([Android Developer - Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)) to store the selected color on click. in the activity, you could set the color of the button from the shared preferences.

On Click

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.apply();
```

Afterwards, you can load this value to set the color of the Background

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE, 0);
//You can use a switch or if else
if(settings.getString(key, defValue).toUppercase.equals("BLUE")){
//set Color Blue as Background
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bluebutton);
}else if(...)
```

I hope this helps :)